Connect Power BI Service to Azure PostgreSQL
I am trying to connect to Azure PostgreSQL to Power BI Service to create dashboards/reports. However, I can't find option to connect to Azure postgreSQL after navigating to Get Data option (green highlighted area in screenshot below:
Image
I tried the same in Power BI desktop and there I could see Azure PostgreSQL option after clicking on Get Data option, to bring in tables in database and successfully created the connection.
Do I need to perform any additional steps to enable the option in Power BI Service (app.powerbi.com)?


Do I need to perform any additional steps to enable the option in Power BI Service (app.powerbi.com)?

If you can't connect to your data source directly from the Power BI service, you can still get your data into Power BI. for this you need to use Power BI Desktop.
Some connectors are visible or supported from Power BI Desktop as you can see in below image:

In Power Bi Service (Web) you can only use data from above DataSource's.
